# AWS DynamoDbLocal v.1.19.0 is broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-local

It seems Amazon released a new version for DynamoDbLocal today (10/08/2022) with an empty jar file into thir specific repository. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release

If you use the recommended dependency from their documentation:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
   <version>[1.12,2.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

... then your build will mysteriously fail from today, becasue maven will load the latest available version below 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Change your dependency to the latest working version:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
   <version>1.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```